# Set an image with CSS content property and make it not stretch

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get an image to replace another image but not stretch, where the background size could be cover. In the demo I've build, the real image is one of an elephant, but I've replaced it with one of a lion via CSS only - I'm not allowed to change the HTML to achieve this.

But it's stretched. Adding `background-size: cover` does nothing. Is there any way of making the lion image not stretched that doesn't change the height of the div or image but instead does it via something like `background-size: cover` or similar? Thanks for any help here.

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
content: url(https://c81s22ku6ih1er8af18cv13c-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Lion.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQudlp3slhvMcKABuQ3hqSbMiBQVUO7nYlDgw_-oj2dUzQ84SEw' />
</div>
```

Comment: `object-fit:cover` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`object-fit: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit).

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  content: url(https://c81s22ku6ih1er8af18cv13c-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Lion.jpg);
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQudlp3slhvMcKABuQ3hqSbMiBQVUO7nYlDgw_-oj2dUzQ84SEw' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using % instead of px?
And also, I would add a `margin: 0;` to the body. That would get rid of the white spaces around the image.

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightgreen;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
content: url(https://c81s22ku6ih1er8af18cv13c-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Lion.jpg);
}
body {
margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQudlp3slhvMcKABuQ3hqSbMiBQVUO7nYlDgw_-oj2dUzQ84SEw' />
</div>
```